# Android View with CustomEvent, passing View as Argument

Tags: android, view, arguments, dataadapter, custom-event

I have a DataAdapter class whose getView() returns a Custom View Class. The View itself is a LinearLayout that contains a few controls, one of which being a CheckBox. It also has a few properties - an ID from the database and it's index in the DataAdapter.

When the CheckBox OnCheckedChange event fires, I want an event to fire in the DataAdapter to so I know to change the underlying data. I can set up a custom Event in the view using an interface:

```
private OnChangedListener mListener;

public interface OnChangedListener{
    public void onChanged();
}

public void setOnChangedListener(OnChangedListener eventListener) {
    mListener=eventListener;
}
```

and call that from the CheckedChange of the CheckBox:

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener checkChanged = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        mListener.onChanged();
    }
};
```

but what I can't do is work out a way to pass back the view as an argument. If I change the interface to return the View:

```
public interface OnChangedListener{
    public void onChanged(MyCustomView arg0);
}
```

I can't return the view from inside the OnCheckedChangeListener():

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener checkChanged = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        mListener.onChanged(this);
    }
};
```

I get an error:
"The method onChanged(MyCustomView) in the type MyCustomView.OnChangedListener is not applicable for the arguments (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){})"

I thought about using a Handler.Post, but then I'd be inside a Runnable so I still can't expose the View.

I'm sure there must be something simple I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. The CheckButtons parent should be the instance of the view I'm looking for:

```
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        ViewParent parent = arg0.getParent();

        if (parent instanceof CustomView){
            Custom myView = (CustomView) parent;
            mListener.onChanged(myView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `mListener.onChanged(this);` does not refer to your View, it refers to the `OnCheckedChangeListener` (the wrapping class). You need to return the View like this:

```
mListener.onChanged(/*reference to your view*/)
```

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. My question was how do I reference the view from inside the OnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: the view you are returning at the end of getView()